# How to check if there's new data added on Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am just new with Google Sheet and Script. Every time a user send a survey through Google Form, the answers were saved to Google Sheet. How do I check if there's added data using Google Script? Because once it detected a new answer I want to get the email address on that answer and do a get request to my site's API.

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/api/" + emailFromSheet);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are triggers to do stuff when something happens in a spreadsheet/sheet. `onFormSubmit` is such a trigger. You can use it to do stuff when form is submitted.

Read more about this installable trigger [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and use below code to install the trigger. Read **Managing triggers manually** section and use **form submit** event for your needs.

Paste this code then put email column index as specified in code. Save.

Try running the function from script editor by **Run > Function > onFormSubmit**

It'll ask for authorization, accept. This run will show an error such as `e is not defined` but don't panic. Test code by submitting the form.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // get email from last submitted values
  // put correct col index here in place of 0
  // col A = 0, col B = 1 and so on ...
  var emailFromSheet = e.values[0];

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://example.com/api/' + emailFromSheet);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: There's onFormSubmit trigger, which has more advantages.

Comment: Thanks. Edited code and instructions and included link to resource.